# What is the quickest way to disable an HTML button after it's clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm creating a web form using AngularJS. This form contains, among other things, three buttons that, when clicked, sort the list items in an unordered list in 3 different ways. I've observed some weird behavior during a lag spike, whereas clicking another of these 3 buttons while the first's method call is still in flight causes a race condition that messes up the unordered list. In order to prevent this, I'm trying to make each of these 3 buttons disabled during the period of time when any of their onClick functions are running.

To really push this fix to its limits, I have automated tests running that are designed to click between two of these buttons alternately and repeatedly. The idea is that, even with the test software clicking between the two buttons at super-human speed, the second button will not be clickable while the first button's method call is in flight.

I've tried several methods to do this - using the ng-disabled property on each button, tied to a scope-level variable that each method toggles to true and false at the beginning and end of their methods, manually disabling the buttons at the beginning and end of each function - and yet in each case, the test reports that the race condition is still being triggered.

Considering that I'm manually disabling these buttons at the very beginning of their method calls, it appears that even this isn't enough. Does anyone know the absolute earliest point where I can disable the button after it's been clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Theorem:**

The problem you are having is that the script that is running effectively queues the click. The browser window is unresponsive as long as the event handler is running, but the click is still recorded, and processed as soon as the handler is done,

So what you do is

In handler1:

- Disable button2
- Do all the processing
- Enable button 2

Only after that, the click is processed (even though you clicked it during the event handling). Because button2 is enabled at that time, handler2 will also run.

**Proof:**

With a piece of HTML, you can check that:

```
<button id="test1" onclick="window.test1();">Test1</button>
<button id="test2" onclick="window.test2();">Test2</button>
```

And script:

```
window.test1 = function()
{
    document.getElementById('test2').disabled  = true;
    for (var i=0; i<1000000000; i++);
    document.getElementById('test2').disabled  = false;
    alert('Test1 done'); // Notice: Alert after enabling button 2.
}

window.test2 = function()
{
    document.getElementById('test1').disabled  = true;
    for (var i=0; i<1000000000; i++);
    alert('Test2 done'); // Notice: Alert before re-enabling button 1.
    document.getElementById('test1').disabled  = false;
}
```

Two buttons, each of them will execute a similar, time consuming script. If you click button 1 and then quickly button 2 while the loop is running, you will notice that both handlers are called, but also you'll see that the other button is not (visually) disabled during the loop, because the signal to disable the button is also processed later, just like the click event.

If you press button 2 first (in which the message box comes before enabling the other button), you will notice that button 1 is not disabled while the loop runs, but it is disabled before the message box shows, and will remain so until after the message box is closed.

http://jsfiddle.net/u334tz36/1/

So, I think there is nothing to solve. Actually the two event handlers don't run at the same time but after each other, so there probably isn't even a problem at all.

**Solution:**

If you still think this is anoying and you want to silently consume the clicks, you can do this using a timer. In the following code, the button is not enabled in the handler, but in a timeout that runs 1ms later. That way, once the event handler is done, the (responsive) window will process all the delayed messages. Button 2 will be displayed as disabled, the click is consumed (and discarded) by the disabled button, and 1ms afterwards, the button is enabled:

```
window.enableTest2 = function()
{
    document.getElementById('test2').disabled  = false;
}

window.test1 = function()
{
    document.getElementById('test2').disabled  = true;
    for (var i=0; i<1000000000; i++);
    setTimeout(window.enableTest2, 1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u334tz36/2/

Fun thing is, you just have to give the window the opportunity to prosess the messages that are sent when you click the button. To do this, you don't need seconds at all, 1 millisecond will be enough, and you could even do with less. All you need is to change the order of events: first process all updates that relate to disabling the button and then perform the event handler. Since setTimeout also is message based, it also relies on the same update mechanism (and can actually be delayed by running code. So basically what you do by setting a timeout, is to put the code in the timeout at the end of the queue, no matter how short the given delay is. It's not a matter of time, it's a matter of execution order.

So, that is a possible way to solve it, but like I said, I don't think there is a problem in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer; I'd give even more upvotes if I could. I'll have to simply lower my test expectations.